# How do I upload external apk to firebase test lab using java in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

Every time I run my test I can see \app-debug.apk and \app-debug-androidTest.apk uploading and installing google firebase test lab device. But it is not enough for me. I have an external APK with me and I want to upload it to the device in the firebase and run an automation test on that APK. How can I upload and install an external APK to the application?

Please, someone, help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "external APK"?  Any reason why you can't treat it the same as the ones you've already built and tested yourself?

Comment: I have an APK and for that I have written automation scripts with gradle. I need to test that on firebase test lab

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [testing with gcloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line).  It might also be helpful to read the [documentation on integration with CI systems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous).  The bottom line is that you should have gcloud installed and configured, and use it to upload the APK for testing.  More detailed information about the command line can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run).

Comment: I am using UIautomator2.0 how can I do with that?

Comment: These documentations are telling about  Espresso.

Comment: UIAutomator is supported as well, as noted at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/firebase-console

You'll want to use the --additional-apks flag available in the gcloud beta command for Test Lab:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firebase/test/android/run

Comment: That beta command is needed for additional apks. Thanks @P.Davis